# Plotting and Saving as File in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to plot and save to image file in MATLAB. Here is the code that I am calling inside a 'for' loop:

```
figure
scatter(data_x_pos,data_y_pos,'r*')
hold on
scatter(data_x_neg,data_y_neg,'b')
t = linspace(-80,80);
y = -model.w(1)*t/model.w(2);
plot(t,y,'k');
% need to save this plot to image to a file here
```

Now, this is starter code that I am using for some work and I don't understand it completely (example - the command 'figure'). There have been suggestions to use **saveas** or **print** but I believe I need handles for them. Could someone help me out here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`figure()` is a function which returns a handle to the figure:

```
f = figure()
scatter(data_x_pos,data_y_pos,'r*')
...
```

You can then use this handle to save the figure:

```
saveas(f, 'image.png');
```

Take a look at the [tutorials on Handle Graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html) to learn more.

`scatter`, and `plot` also return handles to the collection of points, or the lines, or whatever, they've plotted.

Comment: Yes. thanks. I figure it out myself too. 
gcf returns the handle to the present figure. So, that works too!

Comment: Better than `saveas` should be `options.Format = format; hgexport(f, 'image.png', options);`. This way, the exported figure will look exactly like it does on your screen.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution that may aid some is to take advantage of the fact that Matlab updates a variable called `gcf` "get current figure handles" each time a figure is created.  Even if a handle is not expressly created with the `f = figure();` handle declaration command, you can still use commands such as `print()` and `saveas()` by calling the `gcf` handle variable.  For example, this block of code might also function for others who do not have the OP's requirement to operate within a large `for` loop with uniquely identified figures:

```
scatter(data_x_pos,data_y_pos,'r*')
hold on
scatter(data_x_neg,data_y_neg,'b')
t = linspace(-80,80);
y = -model.w(1)*t/model.w(2);
plot(t,y,'k');
hold off;
saveas(gcf,'filename','png')
```