# Save exact image output from imagesc in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image: Rainbow]

Hi , I want to save this image produced from `imagesc(magic(3))`, the exact rainbow representation, is it possible?

Thanks.

This question might look like a duplicate , but it is not . I looked at the solution to the similar question at this site , but it did not satisfy me .
I have looked into the Matlab help center and the close answer that I got was this one , at the bottom of http://goo.gl/p907wR

Comment: Is `saveas(gcf,'filename','format')` what you want? Try a vectorized format as .eps

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for answering , could you please elaborate .

Comment: @Werner: How do I get rid of the axes ?

Comment: What do you mean the axes? You dont want the ticks? Do `set(gca,'XTick',[])` `set(gca,'YTick',[])`. I think you may want to set the background as white also: `set(gcf,'Color','w')`

Comment: That will be it , for now .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting and Saving as File in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617843/plotting-and-saving-as-file-in-matlab)

Comment: @Werner: Do you really have to say whether this is a duplicate or not ; nice of you that you pointed .I am adding your reply as a possible answer .

Comment: Well, I am not saying that you didn't research before your question, just that you were unfortunate. Anyway, if people decide that this is not a duplicate, let's facilitate the things x)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To save the figure as a file (don't matter how it was created), one should do:

```
saveas(figureHandle,'filename','format')
```

where figureHandle could be the `gcf` handle, which means: *get current figure*.

As pointed in the discussion, if someone doesn't want the ticks to be shown, the person can add:

```
set(gca,'XTick',[])
set(gca,'YTick',[])
```

where gca is the handle to the current axis, just as `gcf`. If you have more than one axis, don't forget to "handle the handles". They are returned to you when you create them, i.e.:

```
hFig = figure(pairValuedProperties); % Create and get the figure handle
hAxes1 = suplot(2,1,1,pairValuedProperties); % Create and get the upper axes handle
hAxes2 = suplot(2,1,2,pairValuedProperties); % Create and get the bottom axes handle
```

where the pair value are the figure or axes properties declared in the following syntax:

`'PropertyName1',PropertyValue1,'PropertyName2',PropertyValue2,…`

Here are the matlab documentation about the [Figure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html) and [Axes Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html), and about the [saveas method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html).

---

Example:

The image saved with the following code:

```
figure 
imagesc(magic(3))
set(gca,'XTick',[]) % Remove the ticks in the x axis!
set(gca,'YTick',[]) % Remove the ticks in the y axis
set(gca,'Position',[0 0 1 1]) % Make the axes occupy the hole figure
saveas(gcf,'Figure','png')
```

[image: Figure without the white border]

Comment: Well I couldn't avoid the ticks from being shown in my image , and there was a white border around the image as a frame , which is also I didn't want . But I am satisfied that my I have a plausible answer to my schools assignment .Thanks again .

Comment: @MotiurRahman Added an example. Beware that the gca changes if you plot another figure or axes.

Comment: Hugs for the effort , your example works , but I am in Archlinux and nautilus is framing an white border around the image , even though I am not getting the axis right . Thing is I have to do an average filtering of this image , and the white border( which can not be recognized , because the webpage is white ) is really messing up my image( which is actually a grainy image , not this 3x3 image above).So I have to resort to median filtering , which is okayish, but average filtering would have been better .

Comment: My image also have the white border. To remove it, make the axes occupy the hole figure: `set(gca,'Position',[0 0 1 1])`

Comment: Haha , you are just relentless , finally I am happy .

Comment: Congratulations on your intervention. It was of immense relevance for our work. Just one note, please try to provide information regarding the `imagesc(magic(3))` code line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
print -djpeg99 'foo.jpg'
```

This will save it as 'foo.jpg' as you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

```
 imagesc(A);
 %%saving the image
 hgexport(gcf, 'figure1.jpg', hgexport('factorystyle'), 'Format', 'jpeg');
 set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 4 4]);
 print -djpeg filename.jpg -r10
```

Here A will be the matrix from which you will have an image. And the image will be saved as filename.jpg in the directory.