# Matlab save individual subplot as jpg

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot, handles, save-as

In a `for` loop, I create a variable number of subplots that are displayed on a single figure. Can I also save each subplot as a separate, full size plot and image file (preferably JPG)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use copyobj to a new figure and then use saveas with the new figure handle:

Example code that YOU should have provided (see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)):

```
figure
nLines = 2;
nColumns = 3;
handles = zeros(nLines,nColumns)
for line = 1:nLines
  for column = 1:nColumns
    handles(line,column)=subplot(nLines,nColumns,column+(line-1)*nColumns);
    plot([line column]);
    title(sprintf('Cool title (%d,%d)',line,column))
    ylabel(sprintf('Ylabel yeah (%d,%d)',line,column))
    xlabel(sprintf('Xlabel nah (%d,%d)',line,column))
  end
end
```

Here I have the subplot handles saved, but supposing you don't have them saved:

```
axesH = findobj(gcf,'Type','axes','-not','Tag','legend'); % This will change the order from which the axes will be saved. If you need to save in the correct order, you will need access to the subplot handles
nAxes = numel(axesH)
newFig = figure;
for k=1:nAxes
   newAxes=copyobj(axesH(k),newFig);
   % Expand subplot to occupy the hole figure:
   set(newAxes,'OuterPosition',[0 0 1 1]);
   tightInset=get(newAxes,'TightInset');
   set(newAxes,'Position',[tightInset(1:2) [1 1]-(tightInset(3:4)+tightInset(1:2))])
   saveas(newFig,sprintf('axes_%d.jpg',k),'jpg');
   delete(newAxes);
end
delete(newFig);
```

Example of one axes saved:

[image: One subplot example]

To remove the deadspace I used information available [on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832406/remove-deadspace-or-increase-size-of-figure-in-subplot/18834416#18834416).

Comment: Thanks Warner. I end up with a separate file for subplot and colourmaps. I gave you the green tick for showing me how to enumerate the objects on a figure. I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: @user1502755 I couldn't get what is the issue with the subplot and colormap. If you provide a SSCCE from the subplots you're using and how to reproduce the issue you're getting I may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the handle to the `subfigure`'s axis, `ha`, you can use `getframe` and `frame2im` as follows,

```
F = getframe(ha);
[im,map] = frame2im(F);
if isempty(map)
    imwrite(im,'subframe.jpg');
else
    imwrite(im,map,'subframe.jpg');
end
```

Note that this will save the axis *exactly* how it appears on your screen, so resize the figure to your liking before saving.  To use as much figure real estate as possible, tryout the [subfigure_tight](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30884-controllable-tight-subplot) function on MATLAB Central.

Comment: Thanks chappjc. It does as advertised, unfortunately my frames return empty colormaps. I'll keep looking into it. I gave you a useful click.

Comment: You mean the color **bar**?